# Navigation disappears when shrinking window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

The navigation disappears when I shrink the window.
Below is the image before shrinking the window
[image]

Below is the image when the window is reduced

[image]

Below is the code in default.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Header />
    <div class="d-flex flex-0-1-100">
      <SideMenu />
      <v-main class="pl-0">
        <v-container>
          <slot />
          <NavigationLink />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
      <TableofContents />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Below is the code for SideMenu.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useLayout } from 'vuetify';

const { mainStyles } = useLayout();
const marginTop = mainStyles.value['--v-layout-top'];
const maxHeight = computed(
  () => `calc(100vh - ${mainStyles.value['--v-layout-top']})`
);
const minWidth = '250px';
const route = useRoute();
const { navigation } = useContent();
const { baseUrl } = useRuntimeConfig().public;
const matchedNavObject = navigation.value.find(
  (navObject: { _path: string }) =>
    navObject._path === `/${route.params.slug[0]}`
);
const isPathMatched = (path: string, itemPath: string): boolean => {
  // パスの末尾を除いて比較するため、route.pathから末尾のスラッシュを取り除く
  const normalizedPath = path.endsWith('/') ? path.slice(0, -1) : path;
  return normalizedPath.includes(itemPath);
};

const panel = matchedNavObject.children.findIndex((item: { _path: string }) =>
  isPathMatched(route.path, item._path)
);
</script>
<template>
  <client-only>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      border="none"
      class="position-sticky"
      :style="{ maxHeight, minWidth, marginTop }"
      style="height: fit-content"
      width="250"
    >
      <v-expansion-panels :modelValue="panel" :multiple="true">
        <v-expansion-panel
          v-for="(item, i) in matchedNavObject.children"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-expansion-panel-title>{{ item.title }}</v-expansion-panel-title>

          <v-expansion-panel-text
            v-for="(navItem, j) in item.children"
            :key="j"
          >
            <nuxt-link
              :to="`${baseUrl}${navItem._path}`"
              class="text-decoration-none"
              :class="{
                active: `${navItem._path}/` === route.path,
              }"
              >{{ navItem.title }}</nuxt-link
            >
          </v-expansion-panel-text>
        </v-expansion-panel>
      </v-expansion-panels>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </client-only>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
a {
  color: $color-gray-100;
}
.active {
  background-color: $color-blue;
  color: $color-white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
</style>
```

How can I keep the navigation content from disappearing when I shrink the window?
I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice

**I have tried the following**

After removing  from within the  tag of default.vue, the navigation stopped disappearing, but it became focused

```
 <v-main class="pl-0">
   <slot />
   <NavigationLink />
 </v-main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`permanent`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props-permanent) prop to keep the navigation open:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  permanent
  ...
```

---

If you want the sidebar to be hidden on smaller screens, you have to adjust the width of the v-navigation-drawer manually, otherwise the `position-sticky` will keep it from disappearing to the left:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  class="position-sticky"
  v-model="drawer"
  :style="{width: drawer ? '256px' : 0 }"
  ...
```

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: thank you as always. I was able to solve it by adding a permanent

Comment: That's great! I forgot to mention how to make it work if you actually want to hide the navigation on smaller screens or through a button. If that is interesting to you, have a look at the updated answer